# Avoid auto sorting in Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets

I am facing the issue, that during a query I get auto sorting of the group of results. The code is following:
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A1:H;"select A, sum(H) where A is not null group by A ";1)

I would like to keep the original order of elements and not want to get a sorted list.

I would appreciate any help in this topic.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share the sheet?
Maybe is possible with ARRAYFORMULA and UNIQUE, considering you want to group the first column

Comment: I need your mail address, otherwise I can not share the sheet, only as xlsx, csv, etc. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Only an example shared not as editor, you can post the link in you request
or write your data here [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AwVDgtW0dQemxPM_EDVPYhAnGnZ9hFfV-c1rFJEK71Q/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have copied some data into your sheet. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This do what you want

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({FILTER(UNIQUE('PH1'!A1:A);UNIQUE('PH1'!A1:A)<>"")\ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SUMIF('PH1'!A1:A;UNIQUE('PH1'!A1:A);'PH1'!H1:H);ROWS(FILTER(UNIQUE('PH1'!A1:A);UNIQUE('PH1'!A1:A)<>""));1)})
```

maybe I can simplify them, but work and not apply a sort to A,
ask for more if you need

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is this. You can use Filter, Unique and Sumif.

```
={unique(filter(DB!A:A,DB!A:A<>"")),arrayformula(SUMIF(DB!A:A,unique(filter(DB!A:A,DB!A:A<>"")),DB!H:H))}
```

Ciao @Terio

In my video I learn how these functions are used with SUMIF. But it's in Italian : https://youtu.be/aEMrczLlwrE